# Usage of particles で and に with ~的

Tags: particle-に, adverbs, particle-で, na-adjectives, に-and-で

A sentence from JapanesePod 101:

> 北米とヨーロッパでは通常スカートは女性がはくものと思われているが、世界的には多くの男性がスカートをはく。
>
> In North America and Europe a skirt is thought of as something a woman wears, but in many countries men wear skirts.

I don't see why it's 世界的には rather than 世界的では, especially when では is used in the first clause. で seems to fit both clauses (location of action).

Comment: If it said あるの地域では男性がスカートをはく, では would be appropriate because 世界の地域 (parts of the world) is a noun.

Comment: @Ataraxia Did you type あるの地域 but intend to type 世界の地域?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

的 makes 世界 into a 形容動詞 ("na-adjective"), which, when functioning as adverb, turns into ～的に. ～的では is simply ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

世界的には is being translated as "in many countries", but this is just the natural English translation.

"世界的" means "global" or "worldwide", and functions as an adverb when に is attached as Earthling explains. So "世界的には" here is kinda hard to translate literally but means something closer to "globally" or "on a global scale".

> 世界的には Looking at the world as a whole
>   多くの男性が many men
>   スカートをはく。wear skirts.

Or in more natural English: "In many countries men wear skirts."

Comment: I do not see where "countries" comes from, why not just keep "globally"?

Comment: Thanks! But is the contrastive は then marking an adverb (世界的に)? I thought は could only be used on nouns.

Comment: The contrastive は can be used on almost everything.