# Difference between 必死で走る and 必死に走る

Tags: grammar, na-adjectives

I understand that in these expressions the に isn't a particle (I think it indicates the adverbial form of a na-adjective) but I'm not sure what で is:

> 必死**に**走る
>   [*run like crazy*](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BF%85%E6%AD%BB%E3%81%AB%E8%B5%B0%E3%82%8B)
>   必死**で**走る
>   [*run like hell*](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BF%85%E6%AD%BB%E3%81%A7%E8%B5%B0%E3%82%8B)

According to [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12713/19206) it's ungrammatical to use で to make na-adjective adverbial. Still, the English translation is almost the same but the one with で is stronger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「必死で走る」「必死に走る」 both sound perfectly fine to me, and I believe these are both grammatically correct.

---

> I understand that in these expressions the に isn't a particle (I think it indicates the adverbial form of a na-adjective)

I think you're right. According to 明鏡国語辞典, 「必死」 is a 形容動詞/na-adjective, so it conjugates to its 連用形/continuative form 「必死に」 to modify the 用言/conjugatable word 「走る」.

---

> but I'm not sure what で is... it's ungrammatical to use で to make na-adjective adverbial.

In 明鏡, 「必死」 is also categorized as a noun. So the で here is a case particle/格助詞, and is used in the sense of:

> で 〘格助詞〙
>   ❹ 動作を行うときの**様態**を表す。「急ぎ足**で**歩く」...「笑顔**で**答える」「土足**で**上がる」
>   （明鏡国語辞典）

---

> the English translation is almost the same but the one with で is stronger.

「必死に～」「必死で～」 don't really sound different to me... I wouldn't find it wrong if the *crazy* and *hell* were swapped :D

Comment: `動作を行うときの様態を表す。` How does this exactly translate to English? Also, does で in this sense create an adverbial?

Comment: 動作を行うときの様態を表す means "(lit.) expresses the manner of when you do an action." so I think it's like "expresses the manner in which an action is done" or "indicates how an action is done". (Sorry I didn't include the translation in the post.) So yes, you're right that the
 で is turning the noun 必死 into an adverbial phrase, so that it can modify the verb 走る.

Answer (score 1):

> According to [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12712/usage-of-particles-%E3%81%A7-and-%E3%81%AB-with-%E7%9A%84/12713#12713) it's ungrammatical to use で to make na-adjective adverbial.

If you look at it closely, Earthliŋ said in his answer:

> 的 makes 世界 into a 形容動詞 ("na-adjective"), which, when functioning as adverb, turns into ～的に.
>   ～的では is simply ungrammatical.

The answer didn't say "～的で is simply ungrammatical", but it said "～的では" is simply ungrammatical.

But this discovery doesn't seem to answer your question.

Similar to the word 必死, I found 元気.
You can use 元気に走る、元気で走る、元気な姿 just like 必死に走る、必死で走る、必死な形相｛ぎょうそう｝*look/expression*.

I think 必死で走る is made by omitting some expressions in the original phrase like by omitting **な形相** in 必死**な形相**で走る.
This could be said 元気で走る is made by omitting **な姿** in 元気**な姿**で走る.

If so, it is natural that you think 必死で走る seems stronger than 必死に走る, because the latter phrase is a phrase as it is while the former one hides such the expression like 形相 in it.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, it seems that nouns that originally modify a other noun/NP tend to be "na-adjective" and always require に when modifying a verb/verb phrase. 必死 is a noun on its own meaning "certain death" and is not applied that rule.